# Using procmail to remove backdated spam

Tags: spam, procmail

I started getting spam backdated by a few years. Is there an easy way to detect and divert these to /dev/null using procmail?

Answer (score 1):

If the date is definitely present then something simple like:

```
 # The order of the recipes is significant
 #  header format is "Date: Sat, 13 Feb 2010"
 :0
 * ^Date: .*,.*200[0-9]
 /dev/null
```

Comment: Well, if date is not present, then the mail is not backdated, so it's correct your filter does not match in that case :-).

Answer (score -1):

It's actually independent of procmail, but a cronjob that run at a fixed period could do this:

```
find /maildirectory -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {}\;
```

This would delete mail over a week old.

Comment: -1 The question is about deleting *backdated* mails (i.e. the mail arrives now, but with a date of like "2008"). Your solution would just delete mail that *arrived* more than 7 days ago :-(.